# How can i use jquery sessionStorage value from PHP $_SESSION?

Tags: php, jquery, session-storage

I have set some value in session using jquery like given below

```
sessionStorage.setItem('userID','1');
```

Now i wanted to access this "userID" session from PHP like

```
$_SESSION['userID'];
```

Is it possible? If it is not, how can i achieve this?

Comment: Store it in a cookie, PHP doesn't know about `sessionStorage` state - It's only available to the client

Comment: Read this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp) - I think this is what you're looking for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if HTML5 sessionStorage value exists with PHP (like with cookies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271680/check-if-html5-sessionstorage-value-exists-with-php-like-with-cookies)

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION` is managed by PHP, `sessionStorage` is managed by the browser. If you want to do this, you have to pass instructions to JavaScript in the document, like this:

```
<script>
sessionStorage.setItem('userID', "<?php echo $_SESSION['userID']; ?>");
</script>
```

Comment: You're showing how to access a session parameter from javascript, I don't think that's what the OP is asking for

Answer (score 0):

**Answer edited**

The only way I think you can do this is by sending a HTTP request to the server when you set the JS var and set the same value in a PHP SESSION. An alternative is to send this value, via POST, GET, or by storing the content in a COOKIE.

Comment: You are telling to set the value which i already set in PHP session. But my scenario is vice versa, like accessing sessionStorage value from php