# How to clear session if some one clear the cache forcefully in all browsers?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, caching

I am loading image to cache by **preloadImages** function ,

```
function preloadImages() {
if (!preloadImages.cache) {
  preloadImages.cache = [];
}
var img;
for (var i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
  img = new Image();
  img.src = "/path/Pic_("+i+").jpg";
  preloadImages.cache.push(img);
}  }
```

I want to put the images once into the cache so i am using session to call the function once,

```
  if(!sessionStorage.getItem("photoLoaded")){
  sessionStorage.setItem("photoLoaded", true);
  preloadImages();
}
```

If some one clear his cache then all the images also remove from cache but in my session has the value then it will not call to that function again to precache the image.
Thats why i need to clear the session on time of my page load if someone clear the cache.

Comment: Not completely clear to me, but have you tried checking if cache is empty first? If it is then clear the sessionStorage.

Comment: OK I got you, but do you have any method to check the cache that it is empty or not ?

Comment: Never worked with cache until now but if you search you probably going to find something. If not, think how you store things in cache and how you could check if something already exists there.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271680/check-if-html5-sessionstorage-value-exists-with-php-like-with-cookies)